# Remove password for Outlook VBA Project

Tags: vba, outlook

I password protected an Outlook VBAProject and then subsequently forgot the password. Luckily, I exported the VBA code, but I'd like to unprotect the VBAProject.otm file.

I saw online how to do this for Excel projects, but not for Outlook VBA. Any ideas? Tks!

Answer (score 1):

Try using [VBA Password Recovery Master](http://www.rixler.com/vba_password_recovery.htm).

Also see [Download VBA Password Recovery Free Software- Get VBA Password Again!](http://vbaprojectpasswordrecovery.yolasite.com/free-vba-password-recovery-program.php).

Comment: Many thanks. If I don't want to pay, do you know how I can do this myself? (The second one, though advertised as "Free Software", still asks the user to pay).

Comment: the software above is doing a brute force rainbow table method of hacking the VBAProjects password.. which is protected by a weak hash. If you are familiar with programming and password breaking algos it would be possible to roll your own. otherwise get your company to pay for the software, assuming the cost to benefit equation means its cheaper to buy the software and recover the data than to lose the data.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Hex Editor option. Open the OTM file in Hex Editor and try changing the DPB to DPx and save the file and then try opening the vba in outlook.

Note: use the above by creating a copy of OTM file ot it might get corrupted.